# Finding an existing file with access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to find an existing file in a folder location

**Current Code:**

```
Dim FileExistsbol As Boolean
Dim stFileName As String
stFileName = "H:\Test File.txt"
stFileName = Trim(stFileName)
FileExistsbol = dir(stFileName) <> vbNullString
If FileExistsbol Then Kill stFileName
```

**Error:**

The error message is: Type Mismatch
VBA debugs on this line:

```
FileExistsbol = dir(stFileName) <> vbNullString
```

The file does exist so unsure how to resolve this - Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the FileExistsbol variable and then just do something like:

```
If Dir(stFileName) <> "" Then
    Kill stFileName
End If
```